# httphandler in asp.net never gets called

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application running in .net framework 2.0 and hosted on IIS 7.5. The app pool is running in classic mode. I want to intercept all the requests containing .txt files. Below is my entry in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>  
    <handlers>
        <add name="NES.HiLo.Security.CommunityResource, NES.HiLo.Security" verb="*"  path="*.txt" type="NES.HiLo.Security.CommunityResource, NES.HiLo.Security"  />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>

<httpHandlers>
<add verb="*" path="*.txt" type="NES.HiLo.Security.CommunityResource, NES.HiLo.Security"  />
</httpHandlers>
```

When I m making requests for URL like

```
http://local.mysite.com/media/CLT/ResourceUploads/1000277/Test1.txt
```

the handler never kicks in, the control never comes inside the code in the handler.

Any ideas what I m missing? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of registering handler in IIS 7.0 in classic mode, you are missing a couple of attributes:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>  
    <handlers>
        <add name="CommunityResourceHandler" verb="*" path="*.txt"
             type="NES.HiLo.Security.CommunityResource, NES.HiLo.Security"
             modules="IsapiModule" 
             scriptProcessor="FrameworkPath\aspnet_isapi.dll"
             resourceType="File" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>

<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="*.txt" type="NES.HiLo.Security.CommunityResource, NES.HiLo.Security" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Many thanks Andrei. It works!! Could you possibly tell me that If I have these text files in a specific directory e.g. /ResourceUploads/**randomfoldername**/textfiles.txt then how would I set the path attribute above

Comment: @Learner, from what I know this is not possible. However what you can do it placing a new web.config inside this folder, and add handler there. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/673653/728795) for example.