# how to write httphandler to only intercept files in a specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-6, httphandler

I have written a httphandler to intercept all pdf files request via URL from a specific folder and redirect the user to Login page. If the user is authenticated the file can be downloaded. My web.config has the following entry for the interception

```
<httpHandlers>
 <add verb="*" path="/calderdale/*.pdf"
   type="NES.HiLo.Security.CalderDaleAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" />
</httpHandlers>
```

In IIS (6.0) Application extension settings I have added a setting with executable `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll` and extension Pdf.

This works but every pdf file request is getting intercepted rather the the files present in **calderdale** directory.

I have tried solutions given on this link [Mapping specific folder to HttpHandler in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673592/mapping-specific-folder-to-httphandler-in-web-config?rq=1) and removed the application extension setting but then handler does get call at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the httpModule instead of httpHandler.

Comment: I can't use httpmodules as we can only use httphandler to secure files via handlers. e.g. www.domainname.com/foldername/somefile.doc will open the file regardless of httpmodule presence

Comment: @Learner the link you give says to put another web.config file in the folder, the fact that you have path="/calderdale/*.pdf" suggests you have not done what the accepted answer says to do, i.e. put the web.config in the folder 'calderdale' and change path to be path="*.pdf"

Comment: @Learner also have you mapped IIS6 to handle the wildcard extension? http://love2dev.com/#!article/Configure-IIS-for-Wildcard-Extensions-in-ASP-NET ... by telling aspnet_isapi to handle .pdf ASPNET will handle all pdf 'queries'... ALL

Answer (score 6):

I think the trick here is to only register the HttpHandler for that specific directory. This can be done by moving the system.web/httpHandlers content into a location node in your web.config. For instance:

```
<location path="calderdale">  

( system.web/httpHandlers content )

</location>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your main web config:

```
<location path="static">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="*.*" 
          type="NES.HiLo.Security.CalderDaleAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>    
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do this in that way? Wouldn't it be easier to just use ASP.NET provider and protect this folder with required login? A simple webconfig with logic to access/deny would solve your issue. When someone tries to browse that directory, it will be impossible to download the file and will be redirected to the login page. Let me know if I misunderstood something.